# Looking for 90's Action Movie with Robotic antagonist

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember this movie being on HBO or Showtime and from what little I remember, a bunch of bad guys were led by a cyborg-like villain with vision similar to the T800 and one of the bad guys was killed by a female protagonist by being electrocuted when she pulled on the switch to the cable he grabbed after falling in water.

The last scene involved the heroes leaving via helicopter and the main villain being stomped on after attempting to grab the rope ladder by the main protagonist, this causing him to lose his grip and subsequently fall to his death while the main hero says the line, "Ladies and gentlemen.... Elvis has left the building!!!!!" Anyone have a clue to what this movie is?

Comment: check if its here 
https://www.pastemagazine.com/movies/robots/the-100-greatest-movie-robots-of-all-time/#1-roy-batty-blade-runner

Answer (score 2):

Sci-fi thriller [Night Siege](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110901/) (AKA Shadowchaser 2 AKA Armed and Deadly AKA etc. etc., [it has lots of names](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110901/releaseinfo)) from 1994.

> **Terrorists led by an android** take over a nuclear plant and threaten to launch a missile at Washington. While the authorities desperately attempt to negotiate, the terrorists persue their real goal. A plant worker, her son and a tough-guy repair man have other ideas, and attempt to stop the terrorists from inside the plant.

The guy electrocuted, the Terminator-like villain's helicopter death after  falling off the rope ladder, Elvis Leaving the Building, it's all there. Here's the trailer: